# Como criar uma coluna em um loop de uma regressão?

Tags: r

Ola,

Eu tenho o seguinte script, onde estou tentando incluir a coluna com o nome da variável depende a qual o resultado pertence na última linha do  do loop:

```
dataset <- as.data.table(mtcars)
tt <- c("mpg", "vs")
res_list <- lapply(tt, \(coluna) {
  dataset$tt <- dataset[, .SD, .SDcols = coluna]
  #calculando a regressão
  lm(tt ~ cyl + hp + wt, dataset)
  lm$nome <- tt
})
lm <- res_list |>
  purrr::map(summary) |>
  purrr::map(broom::tidy) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

Mas quando roda o script aparece a seguinte mensagem:

***Error in lm$nome <- tt : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable***

Gostaria de saber, como eu faço para criar mais uma coluna onde mostre a qual variável dependente pertence o resultado da regressão. O dataset que eu gostaria de ter no final é esse:

```
<chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <chr> 
1 (Intercept) 38.8       1.79       21.7   4.80e-19  mpg
2 cyl         -0.942     0.551      -1.71  9.85e- 2  mpg
3 hp          -0.0180    0.0119     -1.52  1.40e- 1  mpg
4 wt          -3.17      0.741      -4.28  1.99e- 4  mpg
5 (Intercept)  1.73      0.213       8.14  7.37e- 9  vs
6 cyl         -0.237     0.0656     -3.61  1.19e- 3  vs
7 hp          -0.00119   0.00141    -0.841 4.08e- 1  vs
8 wt           0.107     0.0882      1.22  2.34e- 1  vs
```

Como posso fazer para chegar a esse resultado?

Comment: Boas-vindas. Conforme as [orientações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/582529/como-adicionar-uma-nova-coluna-em-um-loop-de-uma-regress%c3%a3o-linear-no-r#comment1017693_582529), o correto seria editar a pergunta original, não deve duplicar e nem tentar contornar fechamentos, perguntas fechadas podem ser reabertas, desde que os problemas indicados no fechamento tenham sido resolvidos após editar a publicação. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.